# TFS build agent nuget works from cmd but getting authorization error on TFS

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, tfs-2015

We have implemented a CI process on TFS. First step of this CI process is Nuget Restore.

[image]
The Project has some dependency which are stored on a nuget feed on same TFS instance. During restore 401 authorization required error occures.

```
2017-08-22T14:45:56.9497847Z [command]d:\path\3.5.0\NuGet.exe restore 
-NonInteractive D:\somepath\project.sln -Verbosity Detailed
2017-08-22T14:46:03.5127467Z Error downloading 'dependency.4.1.1' from 'http://URL:80/tfs/TFSCollection/_packaging/path/dependency.4.121.1.nupkg'.
2017-08-22T14:46:03.5127467Z Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

But when I try same command which is displaed on the logs from command line. Dependencies are being installed succesfully.

I have checked there is a nupkg here:

> 'http://URL:80/tfs/TFSCollection/_packaging/path/dependency.4.121.1.nupkg'

I have checked following command runs succesfully from commandline on same machine.

```
d:\path\3.5.0\NuGet.exe restore 
-NonInteractive D:\somepath\project.sln -Verbosity Detailed
```

We are planning to open a ticket to Microsoft. But, It seems to me there is a simple trick which we could not see. Do you have any such experience. Why same command Works from command line but not working from TFS. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the authorization issue according to the error message "401 (Unauthorized)"

Please check the **NuGet.Config** file on your agent machine, commonly it should be located in `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`,  make sure you have add the custom feed and set the `packageSourceCredentials` for the feed.

Please see below articles for more information:

- [Use NuGet or dotnet with Team Foundation Server feeds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/tfs)
- [Use NuGet with Team Services feeds](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/nuget-exe)

---

**UPDATE:**

According to the official documents, you have to set the credentials for the custom feed. With the command below it will store the credentials in Nuget.config file. For now, there isn't a way without putting credentials to configuration file

With UserName/Password:

```
nuget sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {your domain username} -password {your domain password}
```

With PAT: (Mentioned in the second link above). See [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate) for how to generate PAT

```
nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT}
```

Comment: thanks. I have checked the document but I have not tried it yet. One more question; instead of putting credentials to config file, I would like to use api key. I dont prefer put credentials to text file. So, is it ok to use 'apikeys'. resource : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file

Comment: @melih.tt The 'apikeys' is for https://www.nuget.org/account/ApiKeys, that means you need to manage the packages in Nuget.org site. In custom TFS feed you can use the normal credentials or PAT. See https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate

Comment: I used following command and problem is resolved. But I am still looking for a solution without putting password to configuration file. Is there any example, how can I do same thing with a PAT?   Solution with username & password:    >nuget sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {your domain username} -password {your domain password}